# Not able to click a checkbox using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
<div class="ann_search_technique_container">
    <h1>DÉTAILS TECHNIQUES</h1>
    <h3>BOȊTE DE VITESSE</h3>
    <div class="ann_search_technique_check_container">
        <div class="ann_search_technique_check_grp">
            <span>Automatìque</span>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ann_search_automatique" 
    formControlName="automatic">
        </div>
        <div class="ann_search_technique_check_grp">
            <span>Manuelle</span>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ann_search_manuelle" 
    formControlName="manuel">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my protractor code is

```
element(by.css('#ann_search_automatique')).click();
```

but it showing an error 'element not visible' while running.

Answer (score 0):

You can give browser.sleep() and try . If that doesn't work you can try with javascriptexecutor

```
var elm = element(by.css('#ann_search_automatique'))
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests this being an issue with the element being visible at the time of interaction.

Firstly, make sure the element is actually visible when Protractor attempts to interact with it. I've had instances whereby a page animation such as an expanding form; renders an element temporarily invisible.

Please try ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf.

This example is taken from the Protractor 5.2.0 API documents:

> **ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf**
>
> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
>   page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only
>   displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. This
>   is the opposite of 'invisibilityOf'.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; 
> // Waits for the element withid 'abc' to be visible on the dom.
> browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your Chackbox is in fact kind of a radio-button-functionality. Either `manuelle` or `automatique` is selected and visible.

Therefore try first to click the parent element:

```
$('ann_search_technique_check_container').click();
```

If that doesn't work, try to always click the 'wrong' element (to trigger it to hide and let the other 'right' element appear).

```
element(by.css('#ann_search_manuelle')).click();
```

Bytheway: `element(by.css())` is the same as `$()`, so this is the same as my line above:

```
$('#ann_search_manuelle').click();
```